# Google maps v3: MarkerImage not scaled in IE 8

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a map where I display markers with a custom image.
The images are displayed correctly, but for some reason when opening the site in IE8 the images aren't resized accordingly.

My images are 64x64px and I want them to be 24x24px.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconUrl);
    icon.size = new google.maps.Size(24,24);
    icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(24,24);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: position, title: title, icon: icon });
    marker.setMap(mb.map.mapObject);
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, but IE8 simply ignores the scaledSize property.
I've also tried using the constructor, but I get the same results.

Has anyone seen this problem before? is it a known bug? what can I do besides hacking the CSS and setting the size there.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just tested it on IE9 and it works with no problems.

Comment: in your head of page, have you these lines `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: I'm using HTML5 so my doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>
Why?

Comment: because it is used to support the CSS and some html tags on ie.
I have already face such problem and it resolve by doing this.

Comment: also try this `<meta http-equiv="X-IE-VERSION-FREEZE" content="IE=8" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the same problem today when using IE8. MarkerImages are not scaled anymore... I have already sent a bug report to Google.
Possible Workaround: Try to use an older version of Google Maps (not the current version 3.7). Here is the code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: I'm seeing very similar behaviour with version 3.7, but with Chrome. My workaround was to pass my size to 'scaledSize' as before, but null for the 'size' argument.

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug over on our issue tracker:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues

Also, please post a reply to this answer once you do file it, so I can track the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the response (I used a workaround with styles). There's another response with a link to the report.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this today in Chrome for Mac too. Going back to 3.6 fixed it for now. This is definitely a bug. I submitted it to google too.

Comment: Here is the bug I submitted: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3908